# discord.py message getting sent multiple times, increases by 1 each time

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Really hard to word in a title. Basically I have a function called #start, which when called at a specific time will send a message on discord asking me to revise until (again) a specific time. But when I go back on discord, it turns out the message has been sent twice. So then I try doing the #start command and it sends the same message 3 times. If I type in #start again, it comes up 4 times. This is my code:

```
if hour == 14:
   await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<@258621320898543616> Why don't you try some science revision now?")
   science = random.choice(sciences) 
   asyncio.sleep(0.5)
   await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<@258621320898543616> lemme see, how about " +science+"? Look over some of that")
   asyncio.sleep(1)
   await bot.send_message(message.channel, "you can take a break at 3:00")
while hour >= 14 and hour < 15:
   msg = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout=3, author=message.author)
   if msg:
      await bot.delete_message(msg)
   hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
```

After the 4th time i type in #start it throws up an error saying:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Message
```

Not sure what's wrong with the code or how I can stop it from happening. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Add a global value indicating whether or not the `#start` command is running.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='#')
start_running = False

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global start_running
    if message.content.startswith('#start'):
        if not start_running:                
            start_running = True
            # do stuff
            start_running = False

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: problem is that the whole code i typed (along with many other while loops and if statements for different times throughout the day) is inside a single `if message.content.startswith('#start'):` statement. And this if statement is inside a `async def on_message()` coroutine. I did this so If i were to type in #start at anytime throughout the day, it would reply with whatever task is set for that time

Comment: and doing it that way prevents me from using anything to do with `message`

Comment: is there any way to make it so the `wait_for_message()` uses a user ID to determine if a message is taken?

Comment: @brandone You can easily do this with `on_message`, see my example above.  If the command is just supposed to respond with the task for that time, why is there a loop at all?

Comment: So it turns out all I needed was to make it not delete a message that said "#start"

Comment: is there a way to make it so the bot only deletes MY messages? Such as using wait_for_message() but inside the brackets it contains my user ID in some way?